# I'm trying to run a basic Spring Boot code but it is throwing some errors

Tags: spring-boot

This is the only file that I created to Start learning Spring Boot.
I'm trying to run a basic Spring Boot code but it is throwing a couple of errors that I couldn't figure it out.

```java
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    
@SpringBootApplication
public class CourseApiApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CourseApiApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildResourceMetadata(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:436)

The following method did not exist:

    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.forElements(Ljava/util/Collection;Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/InjectionMetadata;

The method's class, org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/Users/kranthitalloju/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.0.3.RELEASE/spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/InjectionMetadata.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata: file:/Users/kranthitalloju/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.0.3.RELEASE/spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar
   
Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata
```

Here is the pom.xml file I'm using to deploy the basic Spring Boot app.

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.codeapi.springboot</groupId>

  <artifactId>APIDemo</artifactId>

  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>Java SprinBoot Course API</name>

  

  <parent>

    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>

    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>

    <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>

  </parent>

    

    

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->

        <dependency>

            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>

            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>

            <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>

            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>

            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>

            <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>

            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>

            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>

            <version>5.2.9.RELEASE</version>

        </dependency>

        

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: can you provide your pom.xml ?

Comment: These errors arise when you are mixing modules from different versions of frameworks. In this case you are mixing different versions of Spring itself. Please add your pom or Gradle build file.

Comment: Please provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example or add more detailed code snippets on what you have tried. Thank you.

Comment: Here is my Pom.xml file,

Comment: When you have ten minutes spare, please take a bit of time to learn the code formatting tools in Markdown. They are used all over the web, and are well worth getting to grips with.

Comment: If you inherit from a the parent, remove the versions of the dependencies. You have a version conflict. You also have “beans” twice at different versions!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the `spring-boot-starter-parent`, many versions are managed for you out of the box. Also, the `spring-boot-starter-web` already includes your other dependencies.

You can simplify your pom.xml like so:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <name>Java SprinBoot Course API</name>

  <groupId>org.codeapi.springboot</groupId>
  <artifactId>APIDemo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>
   
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```